# Questions where the code could be made more minimal, but only once the answer is known

Tags: discussion, questions, minimal-reproducible-example

In [Why does an array update corrupt the element value?](https://stackoverflow.com/q/52604935/477476), a user commented the following after someone else has pretty much given the solution in a comment (the problem was an incomplete sensitivity list):

> While you're question isn't a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example it's worth searching for questions whose answers are adding missing signals from process sensitivity lists.

However, my question could only be made more Minimal based on the knowledge that only the sensitivity list of the array-updating process matters!

So my question here is, what is the intended interaction between minimal-ness of a question, and the solution? Should I really edit my question after-the-fact to only contain the part that I now know (from the helpful comment / answer) is the cause of the problem?

Comment: The solution is for others to stop fixating on trying to make the M in MCVE as M as possible. The C and V are more important and if those come at a slight cost of the M then so be it.

Comment: I don't know enough about the topic to be sure, but it *looks* like something which could be narrowed down significantly (if not just solved) through some debugging.

Comment: The problem with examples being non-minimal is that usually makes it more difficult for others with a similar issue to find it and have their own question be answered by an answer to that question. In this case that might not really apply (but, again, I don't know much about the topic at hand).

Comment: That question contains a lot of code. Perhaps the take-away should be to try and make your example more minimal before posting. That way you can often isolate the problem yourself and don't have to ask for help. This approach works for me half the time.

Comment: @jooooeey this is already the result of a lot of minimization: the original CLaSH source was ~300 lines iirc, yielding 6000 lines of VHDL. Not knowing VHDL, this is as little as I could get it.

Comment: It's doesn't need to be "more minimal". The issue a lack of clear problem statement and reproducibility before the testbench was added (complete and verifiable). The "more minimal" is a logical fallacy propagated to this question.

Comment: Assuming it _is_ possible to make it more minimal - that is easier to find for people with a similar issue, it might be worth adding a second, more minimal example at the end of the question for future searches (?)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

One has to know, VHDL is a very noisy language and not as short as e.g. ANSI-C. The OP narrowed his problem down from several thousand lines of auto generated code to few dozen lines. This alone is impressive for the given language!

There is no use in creating a 5 line MVCE, because all the nerds are asking why is this code really needed. Actually, his example was too short, because it did not demonstrate if he used the signal `RESET` to initialize all values after start-up.

Next time you could add a waveform showing the simulation results of the code snippet.

And at the end, I just needed to look at common mistakes and I saw it in less than a minute :).

Comment: See, stuff like this makes you sympathize with all the people who complain about "reviewers closing questions about topics they don't know". Had this question come up in review (it didn't), it probably would have been closed by a bunch of reviewers who don't know VHDL simply because the code looks like a lot to read through, creating unnecessary work for users familiar with VHDL and who patrol the [vhdl] tag who then have to reopen a question that never should have been closed (or that should have been closed with a more appropriate reason) in the first place.

Comment: `" I just needed to look at common mistakes and I saw it in less than a minute"` -- In that case, there is a good probability that it's a duplicate and should be closed.

Comment: @BrockAdams I disagree here. The cause it a very common one, but it surfaces in many different errors. Or like in his case, no error message but a false output value. It's not like a "missing semicolon" problem.

Answer (score 0):

**TL;DR: Learning how to find a minimal example not only helps to ask better SO question, but actually helps to learn how to debug programs on your own. It will even help you when the issue comes from a library you are depending on and not from a part of your own code.**

Disclaimer: I do not know about VHDL, so I'm answering this question at a general level.

Here are a few techniques I apply myself when looking for a minimal example (hint: they all come down to binary search).

Sometimes you have an exception and you don't know where it came from. In that case, you can try removing about half of your code, and see if you still get the exception. If you do, it seems the exception comes from the first half of your code. If you don't, put back the second half and remove the first half : you should get the exception from the second half. Repeat the process until you've located the exact line where the exception happens. If it's a function call that raises the exception, repeat the process in the body of that function.

Sometimes your code doesn't give you an exception, but you get an unexpected output. In that case, you can add at about half of your code some quick code that throws an exception if the intermediate result is wrong. If you get the exception, the error is happening in the first half of your code. Otherwise it's happening in the second half. Repeat the process.

Sometimes your code produces a side effect (writing to the database for instance) that is not quite right. If you don't know at which point this side effect happens, you can add some code that checks whether the side effect happened or not at about half your code. Repeat until you find exactly where the side effect happens.

A common question is : how can I remove the first half of my program? It's needed for the second half to be able to run!

Sure it is when you want to treat all inputs equally. But in our case, we want to narrow it down to a specific line of our program. If we can debug for one specific input, it is very likely we will be able to handle all inputs afterwards. So let's consider only a single specific input. With that in mind, we can suddenly start replacing a lot of calculations by their values in the case of that specific input. That way, we can "skip" the algorithms required in the first half of the program by immediately supplying to the second half the intermediary results that we hard code for the specific input we are considering. And thus we can truly "cut our code in half" at each step of the process.

So all in all, learning how to produce minimal example without knowing the answer is a skill you should master to become an awesome developer ;)

Hope all that helps someone.

Comment: *`I do not know about VHDL`* VHDL is the worst. Imagine writing a program in a language where you had to define all of your own keywords. `var a = 2;` you write and the compiler replies, "missing definition for: `var`." So you create a new file called `var.def` and write in it `var is var` (along with some boilerplate) and save it so the compiler's happy: it already knew what variables *were* it just didn't know what keyword you wanted to use. (Note: this might be oversimplified and hyperbolic, but that approximates the experience I had in college)

Comment: I see ... not looking forward to use that language then! I guess they did that for a reason? But it's starting to get off-topic: I'll look it up by myself. Thanks!

Comment: Its a hardware design language. You're unlikely to ever need it.

Comment: @Draco18s why is that so? This strongly depends on what you do, VHDL is not uncommon in certain fields, embedded programming just as an example.

Comment: @KamiKaze If Aymeric hasn't *yet* encountered it, it's *unlikely* that he will in the future. Not impossible, but *unlikely* as he is not currently working in a field that utilizes it. My statement was not applicable to a broad audience, but to a narrow one.

Answer (score -5):

> Should I really edit my question after-the-fact to only contain the part that I now know (from the helpful comment / answer) is the cause of the problem?

Yes.
The "official" purpose of comments is to clarify posts, and this frequently involves solidifying the true nature of the question. So if you get information from a comment that lets you do that, then it's helpful to edit the post accordingly.

In general, if a comment gives you an idea to make the post simpler and/or easier to understand, then you will get more and better responses by making the revision.

---

In this case, you say you have "the answer".  If that is true, then you might best serve the site (and yourself) by one or more of the following:

- Vote/flag to close the question as a duplicate if you sincerely believe that your question's phraseology will help others searching for the same issue.
- Delete the question, if the above is not the case, and it's all been covered before.
- Self answer the question if you feel that the Q&A are different, *in a non-trivial way*, from all the previous ones on the same topic